# Rails turbolink requests are submitted twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `PagesController` where I'm creating a new record like this:

```
  def new
    @page = Page.create(status: "draft", title: "Temporary title")
  end
```

I'm using `Page.create` because the user should immediately be able to `add page_items` to the new page and the associations need a record with an ID.

The problem is that whenever I click "new record" I create two new records. Not just one.

**Edit:** The problem appears to be related to Turbolinks. If i use the normal "new page" link, two requests are made to the server, so two pages get created. If i visit the link manually or open the link in a new tab i get one record.

This problem is across the whole app. All links create two get requests to the server.

**Edit 2:** here are the server response when i click on the "new page" link:

```
Started GET "/pages/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-28 22:39:41 +0100
Processing by PagesController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = '040__V_8SbdLhYxbjd1sYQ' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."subdomain" = 'ohenrik' LIMIT 1
  Page Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" IN (3)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "pages" ("created_at", "status", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 28 Feb 2014 21:39:41 UTC +00:00], ["status", "draft"], ["title", "Temporary title"], ["updated_at", Fri, 28 Feb 2014 21:39:41 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered shared/_form_errors.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered pages/_rich_link_button.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered pages/_rich_content_toolbar.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered pages/_rich_link_button.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered pages/_rich_excerpt_toolbar.erb (0.5ms)
  PageItem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "page_items".* FROM "page_items" WHERE "page_items"."page_id" = $1 ORDER BY (case when page_items.ancestry is null then 0 else 1 end), page_items.ancestry, position  [["page_id", 55]]
  Rendered pages/_form.html.erb (5.6ms)
  Rendered pages/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_navigation.html.erb (27.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_notice.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 46.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)


Started GET "/pages/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-28 22:39:42 +0100
Processing by PagesController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = '040__V_8SbdLhYxbjd1sYQ' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."subdomain" = 'ohenrik' LIMIT 1
  Page Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" IN (3)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "pages" ("created_at", "status", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 28 Feb 2014 21:39:42 UTC +00:00], ["status", "draft"], ["title", "Temporary title"], ["updated_at", Fri, 28 Feb 2014 21:39:42 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered shared/_form_errors.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered pages/_rich_link_button.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered pages/_rich_content_toolbar.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered pages/_rich_link_button.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered pages/_rich_excerpt_toolbar.erb (0.4ms)
  PageItem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "page_items".* FROM "page_items" WHERE "page_items"."page_id" = $1 ORDER BY (case when page_items.ancestry is null then 0 else 1 end), page_items.ancestry, position  [["page_id", 56]]
  Rendered pages/_form.html.erb (4.9ms)
  Rendered pages/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_navigation.html.erb (41.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_notice.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 66ms (Views: 60.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

**Note, removed some of the extra unnecessary code to make the question clearer. the problem was related to an extra jquery plugin that had jquery already included. this resulted in remote links (also turbolink) being fired twice. se my answer bellow**

Any hints or answers to what might be wrong is appreciated! :)

Comment: I don't see anything here that would create two records.  Do you have any callbacks, filters or other code that may be getting run when you hit the create action?

Comment: No i there are no extra callback except one validation. And removing that did not help.

Comment: However i noticed now that if i visit the locallhost:3000/pages/new link manually only one record is created, also if i open the record in a new tab. The error only occurs if i follow the "new page" link. So might this be related to turbolinks?

Comment: Can you share the server logs

Comment: I have shared to output in my question above :)

Comment: I don't see any server logs in the question. Also, can you share the view with the new link?

Comment: Hi, sorry i deleted them, but hey are back now. Please tell me if you need anything more. I removed the assets files from the server log because it became a long list.

Comment: Thanks for that. Also, can you share the view with the `new` link?

Comment: Added the view with the "new page" link.

Comment: Try with `data-no-turbolink` in the new link `<%= link_to 'New Page', new_page_path, class: "btn btn-default pull-right", data: { no_turbolink: true } %>`

Comment: @KirtiThorat this works, however the problem occurs on all turbolinks. (i.e. all links in the entire app). How do i get turbo links to work again. i might need to write a new question for that?

Answer (score 0):

use `find_or_create_*` method instead of `create`.

```
def new
  @page = Page.find_or_create_by_status_and_title("draft","Temporary title")
end
```

The only possible reason is your controller might be getting two different request. There might be some client error like javascript is reloading all page, or user is clicking the button multiple times. You can check logs and confirm it.

[Read More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943626/prevent-duplicates-from-saving-in-active-record-and-return-the-object-that-was)

Comment: Hehe, nice hack. It solves the problem initially, but it is still not a complete solution. The problem is that the user will not be able to create a new page before he has renamed the old default titles. You are right that the request is made twice. I think this is caused by turbolinks. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: the above will fix it. You can also click on "read more here".

Comment: The above answer appears to fix the problem, but it actually only removes the symptom (the symptom being two records instead of one). The problem (i believe) is related to turbolinks sending two requests rather than one when i click "New page"

Comment: Ohh sorry, where did you placed your `javascript_include_tag` tag, it should be inside `<head>` tag.

Comment: No problem :) The `javascript_include_tag` is placed in the `<head>` section.